# Add backslash to string

Tags: c#, string, path, backslash

I have a path and I want to add to it some new sub folder named test.
Please help me find out how to do that.
My code is :

```
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures);
 Console.WriteLine(path+"\test");
```

The result I'm getting is : "c:\Users\My Name\Pictures            est"

Please help me find out the right way.

Comment: \t is a tab either use \\t or use path+@"\test"

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Do not try to build pathnames concatenating strings. Use the [Path.Combine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx) method

```
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures);
Console.WriteLine(Path.Combine(path, "test"));
```

The [Path class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3bdzys9w.aspx) contains many useful static methods to handle strings that contains paths, filenames and extensions. This class is very useful to avoid many common errors and also allows to code for a better portability between operating systems ("\" on win, "/" on Linux)

The Path class is defined in the namespace `System.IO`.
You need to add `using System.IO;` to your code

Answer (score 20):

You need escape it.  `\t` is an escape-sequence for Tabs `0x09`.

`path + "\\test"`

or use:

`path + @"\test"`

Better yet, let `Path.Combine` do the dirty work for you:

`Path.Combine(path, "test");`

`Path` resides in the `System.IO` namespace.

Answer (score 8):

There are two options:

1. Use the @ symbol e.g.: path + @"\test"
2. use a double backslash e.g.: path + "\\test"

Answer (score 6):

string add;

```
add += "\\"; //or :"\\" means backslash
```

Answer (score 3):

Backslash `'\'` is an escape character for strings in C#. 
You can:

- use `Path.Combine`

  ```
  Path.Combine(path, "test");
  ```
- escape the escape character.

  ```
  Console.WriteLine(path+"\\test");
  ```
- use the verbatim string literal.

  ```
  Console.WriteLine(path + @"\test");
  ```

Answer (score 1):

the backslash is an escape character, so use
`Console.WriteLine(path+"\\test");`
or
`Console.WriteLine(path+@"\test");`