# SQLite no such table found:moz_places in C#

Tags: .net, sqlite

I am doing task to get history of Mozilla Firefox in my desktop application here is my code but i get Error No such table found:moz_places ,I searched out every where but i did't get solution .
I get Reference of   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/Places/Database
and  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uRKeZSCwlyE

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string Mozilla = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + @"\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\iv6i2j75.default\places.sqlite";
            SQLiteConnection cn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + Mozilla + ";Version=3;New=False;Compress=True;");
            cn.Open();
            SQLiteDataAdapter sd = new SQLiteDataAdapter("select url,title,visit_count,last_visit_date from moz_places", cn);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            sd.Fill(ds);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            cn.Close();
        }
```

here is my error snap ..Any Suggestion will appreciated...!!

[image]

Comment: close firebox - put the path as hard coded: string Mozilla = "c:/users/u1/....."; - build the project , run it as administrator from windows explorer (not from visual studio)... you can use http://sqlitestudio.pl  to open the file and to see if the tables exists or not.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add backslash to string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16899522/add-backslash-to-string)

Comment: CL :NO I tried That ....